# Refer applicationID of Azure AD Service principal

Tags: azure-active-directory

when an application is registered to Azure AD via consent, a service principal is created. The application object resides in another tenant.
From my understanding, the applicationID refers back to the application object.

- When the application object resides in another tenant, is it possible to find out in which tenant based on the applicationID? Or may there is another value on a service principal which is an indicator where the application object resides (if its not an app registration).

BR
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you need to make sure the service principal is in your tenant.

Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory`-> `Enterprise applications` in the portal. Search for the `APPLICATION ID` (select the `Application Type` with `All Applications` option), then you will find the service principal, copy the `OBJECT ID`.

Then navigate to the [MS Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), call the MS Graph API : [`Get servicePrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-beta) as below, in the result you could find the `"appOwnerOrganizationId": "xxxxxxxx"`,`"publisherName": "Organization name"` which is the tenant id and name you are looking for.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{OBJECT ID}
```

[image]

Comment: cool thanks for your answer. Is it possible to find out the Azure AD tenant or something like that based on the "appOwnerOrganizationId"?

Comment: @Thomas What the information of the Azute AD tenant do you want to find? The `appOwnerOrganizationId` is already the `Tenant ID`.

Comment: the tenant name, can i do a graph query based on that tenant ID?

Comment: @Thomas the `publisherName` is the tenant name, may be you want to get the one like `joyorg.onmicrosoft.com`?

Comment: yes i want to see the .onmicrosoft.com tenant name. Because if i check some service principals, for example "graph Explorer" where it´s just "Microsoft" as publisher name. And based on the appOwnerOrganizationID, it looks like there are multiple tenants. Or if i check the service principal of doodle, the information is not that helpful as the publisher is "Microsoft Accounts"

Comment: @Thomas 1.Are you sure `it looks like there are multiple tenants`? AFAIK, the organization id (i.e. tenant id) is unique. 2. I don't think you can get the .onmicrosoft.com tenant name with the tenant id via MS Graph, even if your account is in the tenant, then you can use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/organization` to get the details of your tenant including the .onmicrosoft.com tenant name.